# Sorting multi dimensional array by nested property

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I gave an array of scores and wish to produce a ladder based on points. Each score elementt has an array with a team name, wins and points acrued.I wish to produce a ladder array with the team with the most points being on top or first in the array:

```
var scores = [["team1", "15", "167"], ["team2", "13", "185"], ["team3", "16", "180"]]
    //scores = [[team, wins, points], [team, wins, points]] 
print(scores) //prints the order of the array as above
    // I want to sort by points and output: [["team2", "13", "185"], ["team3", "16", "180"], ["team1", "15", "167"]]
```

Comment: `scores.sort{$0.last! > $1.last!}`. You should consider structuring your data in a `struct` with 3 properties: team, wins and points. And make it conform to `Comparable` protocol sorting it by points descending

Comment: Leo gave you the answer, but note that an array of arrays is a poor choice of data structures for this sort of thing. An array of structs, named tuples, or dictionaries would be much better because with all of those, you could indicate which sub-field is the team name, which is the # of wins, and which is the point score. (Leo, you should post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it and I can up-vote it.)

Comment: Thanks Leo for your suggestion, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

While I share the opinion mentioned in the comments that an array of arrays is far from being an ideal data structure, I still think it's a valid question how to sort this data:

```
let sortedScores = scores.sorted { Int($0[2])! > Int($1[2])! }
```

That code is similar to the solution mentioned in a comment, but there the `points` value is compared as string which is not what you want; if you had a 4th entry with a `wins` value of `27` it would end up as first score in the result because `"27" > "185"`. By converting the Strings to Ints the comparison works as expected (`185 > 27`)